# SOAP Error Unknown Content-Encoding

Tags: error, soap

i got a new SOAP Error Unknown Content-Encoding after updating php to 5.4

phpinfo(); at magento:
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip,deflate,sdch

**getLastRequestHeaders :**

```
POST /index.php/api/soap/index/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.abc.de
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"
Content-Length: 2592

SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => Unknown Content-Encoding
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/kusy/module/magentoapi/magento.class.php
    [line:protected] => 158
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [function] => __doRequest
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0
```

** Update 15:02 **

i check the sample code from magento api website to create a product. this is the result:

```
    __getLastRequestHeaders :
    POST /index.php/api/soap/index/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.abc.de
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    SOAPAction: "urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction"
    Content-Length: 2552


    __getLastResponseHeaders :
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Thu, 03 Jul 2014 13:01:18 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.4.30-1~dotdeb.0 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.7(2010-08-16) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.30-1~dotdeb.0
    Content-Encoding: none
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 506
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

    object(SoapFault)#2 (9) {
      ["message":protected]=>
      string(24) "Unknown Content-Encoding"
      ["string":"Exception":private]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["code":protected]=>
      int(0)
```

**I solve the Problem.**

In php.ini

```
    zlib.output_compression = On
```

And in php:

```
    $client = new SoapClient($url, array('compression'=> SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,'trace'=>true,'exceptions'=>true));
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted by OP:

> **I solve the Problem.**
>
> In php.ini
>
> ```
>    zlib.output_compression = On
> ```
>
> And in php:
>
> ```
>    $client = new SoapClient($url, array('compression'=> SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,'trace'=>true,'exceptions'=>true));
> ```

Comment: where exactly in PHP did you put this line?

I have fixed the zlib.output_compression=on issue, but this 500 error still lingers.